# Master Detail in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-detail

I have two tables.

```
tbl_Request(PKRequestID, RequestCode) and tbl_Personnel(PKPersonID, PerosnelName FKRequestID)
```

FKrfequestID is a foreign key to tbl_request.
I have a grid view in Requests.aspx page that shows tbl_request records. There is a "New Item" button in this page too. When user clicks this button RequestInsert.aspx page opens. In this page user enters some data like RequestCode and hits the "Next" button and goes to Personel.aspx page which contains a gridview that shows the personnel who are related to the request. In this page user should define Personnel who are related to the request. When the whole process finishes user hits "save" button. Both tables will be update when user clicks on "save" button. How can I implement Personel.aspx page?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. **"When user wants to add new record to tbl_Reque..."** and **"in database until user confirms the whole process..."** are creating the confusion to me. Please clarify.

Comment: I edited the question Krishanu Dey.

Comment: can you post the html of `Personel.aspx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE IS AN APPROACH :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dttbl = new DataTable();
        dttbl.Columns.Add("PKPersonID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dttbl.Columns.Add("PerosnelName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dttbl.Columns.Add("FKRequestID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Session["MyDataTable"] = dttbl;
    }
}
protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();

    row1["PKPersonID"] = txtid.Text ;
    row1["PerosnelName"] = txtname.Text;
    row1["FKRequestID"] = Session["FKRequestID"];
    t.Rows.Add(row1);

    Session["MyDataTable"] = t;
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable t2 = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection_string"
        using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            //Here you are inserting values to tbl_Request
            if (con.State == 0)
                con.Open();
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Request (PKRequestID,RequestCode) VALUES (@PKRequestID,@RequestCode)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PKRequestID", Session["PKRequestID"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestCode", Session["RequestCode"]);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in t2.Rows)
        {
            //Here you are inserting values to tbl_Personnel
            using (SqlCommand command2 = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (con.State == 0)
                    con.Open();
                command2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Personnel (PerosnelName, FKRequestID) VALUES ( @PerosnelName, @FKRequestID)";
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerosnelName", txtname.Text);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FKRequestID", Session["PKRequestID"]);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have done this. But I dont know how to implement Personel.aspx page. How I should implement Insert? Because in this step Request is not inserted in the table I cant insert into tbl_personel.

Comment: Here in `Personel.aspx` page user just have to select a Personel from the grid view. Am I right?

Comment: No. there should be a "new" button. when user clicks on it another page will open. He enters personnel info and clicks ok. new added personnel should be appear in the gridview. But should not be inserted into tbl_personnel until user clicks "save" button.

Comment: Are `PKPersonID` & `PKRequestID` auto generated?

Comment: PKPersonnelID is auto generated. But I generate PKRequestID manually. both are GUID.

Comment: Thank you so much krishanu. I still have another problem. How to implement editing tbl_personnel records?

Comment: Post a separate question for **"How to implement editing tbl_personnel records?"**

Comment: Please inform me by leaving a comment here after posting question about **"How to implement editing tbl_personnel records?"**

Comment: I asked new new question krishanu. Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772139/how-to-implement-editing-master-detail-records