# How to implement editing Master/Detail records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

```
tbl_Request(PKRequestID, RequestCode) and tbl_Personnel(PKPersonID, PerosnelName FKRequestID)
```

FKrfequestID is a foreign key to tbl_request. I have a grid view in Requests.aspx page that shows tbl_request records. There is a "New Item" button in this page too. When user clicks this button RequestInsert.aspx page opens. In this page user enters some data like RequestCode and hits the "Next" button and goes to Personel.aspx page which contains a gridview that shows the personnel who are related to the request. In this page user should define Personnel who are related to the request. When the whole process finishes user hits "save" button. Both tables will be update when user clicks on "save" button. How can I implement Personel.aspx page?

Here is the code for personnelaspx.cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dttbl = new DataTable();
        dttbl.Columns.Add("PKPersonID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dttbl.Columns.Add("PerosnelName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dttbl.Columns.Add("FKRequestID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Session["MyDataTable"] = dttbl;
    }
}
protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"]; 
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();

    row1["PKPersonID"] = txtid.Text ;
    row1["PerosnelName"] = txtname.Text;
    row1["FKRequestID"] = Session["FKRequestID"];
    t.Rows.Add(row1);

    Session["MyDataTable"] = t;
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataTable t2 = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection_string"
        using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            //Here you are inserting values to tbl_Request
            if (con.State == 0)
                con.Open();
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Request (PKRequestID,RequestCode) VALUES (@PKRequestID,@RequestCode)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PKRequestID", Session["PKRequestID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestCode", Session["RequestCode"]);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in t2.Rows)
    {
        //Here you are inserting values to tbl_Personnel
        using (SqlCommand command2 = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            if (con.State == 0)
                con.Open();
            command2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Personnel (PerosnelName, FKRequestID) VALUES ( @PerosnelName, @FKRequestID)";
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerosnelName", txtname.Text);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FKRequestID", Session["PKRequestID"]);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement edit mode? In this mode I want users be able to delete personnel or add them?

Comment: So you want to delete a personnel from `personnelaspx` page before they r saved to DB. am i right?

Comment: No. Imagine that a user has added a request and it's related personnel. I want the user be able to click on a Edit button on Request.aspx page and be able to edit request info and also edit or edit the personnel that are added to this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You need to use `session` to store the `tbl_Request.PKRequestID` of the record that is to be edited when user clicks `Edit button`. After that re direct the user to a new page `Edit_Requests_Personnel.aspx` where you can edit the records.

Comment: Do you know how can I get the selected row when user clicks on Edit in gridview?

Comment: post your html of gridview. I will help you.